# How to overlay one MATRIX over another?

Tags: java, math, matrix, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to map a point onto a warped grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601600/how-to-map-a-point-onto-a-warped-grid)

Let's imagine we have two matrixs. One is a simple straight matrix and the other one is distorted.

We need to scale down the distorted matrix and place it in a certain point on the straight one, making the straight matrix distort.

For example, in the drawing below the red vertexes in the straight matrix should distort, according to the scaled down distorted matrix.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: are you getting matrices as pictures or as variables n points?

Comment: Its an array of points, like [0,0][1,0][2,0] , etc.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601600/how-to-map-a-point-onto-a-warped-grid

Comment: Can you give us a visual approximation of what the desired result should be?